# Regular expression for email and 'No Email'

Tags: c#, regex

Need regular expression to validate email address also if user don't have email, user able to type 'No Email'. such that regular expression should validate 'No Email' as a valid string.

Comment: First question, zero effort. Classic..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Please read this stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask as it stands this is a very low quality question

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this question has been asked alot already, what kind of user experience forces a user to type an exact string "No Email" just to point out they don't have one?

Comment: @Kippie, indeed.  Why not just leave it blank and state the field is optional. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @"^(([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)|(No Email))$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your regex with an or expression `|`

```
var regex = "(.+@.+\..+|No Email)"
```

The validation part need some improvement (not RFC compliant) but you get the idea.